# getting - error: package android.content does not exist import android.content.Context; for my react native - android run

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, node-modules, react-native-firebase

error file -
node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/android/src/main/java/io/invertase/firebase/common/UniversalFirebaseModule.java:21:

targeted sdk - build.gradle files are all aligned, sdk manager sdk updated,
this statement is also imported
import android.content.Context;

and in the file

public class UniversalFirebaseModule {

UniversalFirebaseModule is showing in gray

i tried, clean , node module delete - npm install , link, sdk manager tool updation, all did from my side, no online answer for this specific - android.content package....

Answer (score 0):

please ensure that the Firebase version in your package.json matches. If it's the same, consider downgrading from version 18, as I've encountered a similar issue before.